# How do I test (jest) to expect return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Using Jest how do I test for `return`

For example using Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    const orders = await getOrders();

    if (!orders) {
      console.log("There is no Orders");
      return; //<< How do test this?
    }

    // Something else
  } catch (err) {
    throw new;
  }
};
```

I am able to test the console log but I also like to test to expect `return` as well

Currently I am using this in the test:

```
  it("should terminate if there is no order", async () => {
    console.log = jest.fn();

    let order = await func.handler();
     expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('There is no Orders');
  });
```

Comment: well, you need to return something from the function if you are testing if a function returns a result.

Comment: Depends, what will `order` be if there are orders? A `return;` will return `undefined` so you could test if it is `undefined` or what you expect that it should be when there are orders (an Array?).

Comment: It looks like you want to expect not `toThrow()` or not `.rejects` or both, both scenarios are documented https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function with no return will return 'undefined' so you can test for that using not.toBeUndefined();

Comment: Is there alternative way instead of `return;` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back depends if not having orders is an error case or not. You could `return`, `return false`, throw an Error if it should be handled as error, ... . But the use-case of your function is not clear enough to be able to tell how you should handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Necroposting here, but jest now has `toReturn` and `toReturnWith`, without and with arguments assessing, accordingly. And also there are `toHaveReturned` and `toHaveReturnedWith` to fit new language.

You can use it on `spyOn`'ed variant of your `handler`:

```
it("should terminate if there is no order", async () => {
  jest.spyOn(func, "handler")
  console.log = jest.fn();

  let order = await func.handler();
  expect(func.handler).toHaveReturned();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply expect the value to be undefined:

```
expect(order).toBeUndefined();
```